# ¿Por qué se dice "atracadores de bancos" en vez de "atracadores de banco"?

Tags: gramática, plurales

¿Por qué se dice "atracadores de bancos" en vez de "atracadores de banco"? El siguiente es el título de un [artículo](https://www.lne.es/gijon/2019/06/29/expertos-atracadores-bancos-logran-huir/2495466.html) que he encontrado.

> Dos expertos atracadores de bancos logran huir tras un nuevo asalto en Gijón.

Comment: No entiendo la duda, si atracan bancos es normal que sea en plural.

Comment: Por favor, incluye el enlace cuando sea posible, Maurice.

Comment: Lo genérico suele ir en plural.  Por eso, cuando hacemos una palabra compuesta, casi siempre va en plural incluso para palabras que no suelen contar con forma plural como *paraguas*.  Podríamos hacer la palabra *atracabancos* pero no *atracabanco*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece razonable suponer que acciones como el atraco a un banco, el robo de una cartera, o la evasión de impuestos no sean hechos aislados sino repetitivos. Así es común referirse a:

> El atracador de banco**s**
>
> La ladrona de cartera**s**
>
> Los evasores de impuesto**s**

En singular indicaría un hecho concreto:

> El atracador **del** banco de la esquina
>
> La ladrona de **tu** cartera
>
> Los evasores **del** impuesto de sucesiones

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!