# Significado de «muerte al jurado»

Tags: gramática, significado

¿Cuál es el significado de "muerte al jurado"?

Es el título de una película. Yo lo cambiaría a "la muerte del jurado".

La sinopsis está abajo:

> "Laura Price analiza un supuesto caso de suicidio que para ella es un
>   asesinato. Dos personas que formaron parte de un jurado años antes
>   aparecen muertas, pero cada tres días hay nuevos cadáveres."

Comment: Maurice: cada vez te edito lo mismo en forma de poner título más representativo y citar la publicación utilizando un bloque de citación. ¿Te animas a mejorar el formato de tus publicaciones sin que lo hagamos otros? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola, fedorqui: ¿No los hago correctamente? Creía que sí, como en este enlace ... ¿O no? Perdone por las molestias ~

Comment: Lo haces bien pero siempre es mejorable :) Fíjate en tu [anterior pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31036/1674), como puse un título más descriptivo y añadí un bloque de citación a la parte de la frase que mencionas. Revisa https://spanish.stackexchange.com/editing-help y https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/formatting para tener más detalles sobre cómo hacerlo. En general, mirando otras publicaciones irás cogiendo ideas de cómo poner formato para que todo luzca más claro.

Comment: Lo de los títulos en español daría para comentarios amplios, sobre todo si involucran traducciones. En España la serie "Third rock from the Sun" se tradujo como "Cosas de marcianos". La traducción literal (y correcta) del título no le habría dicho mucho a la gente, y esa serie reemplazaba en la sobremesa a "Cosas de casa" (que era "Family  Matters"), por lo que le pusieron un título "parecido". Batman Begins matuvo el título original en España mientras que era "Batman inicia" en Hispanoamérica, "The Fast & the Furious" es "A todo gas", "Die Hard" es "la jungla de Cristal", "Jaws" es "Tiburón"

Comment: Backtranslating: *Death to the Jury*.  Not *Death of the jurors*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comprensión, fedorqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Muerte al jurado" es una exhortación donde se ha omitido el imperativo del verbo **dar**, equivale a

> Demos muerte al jurado

o

> Dad muerte al jurado

En tu caso concreto, dado que aparecen muertos varios jurados, lo que quiere reflejar la frase es que están muriendo tantos jurados que da la impresión de que alguna autoridad superior hubiera ordenado una sentencia de muerte sobre ellos.

El cambio de preposición, "al" por "del", cambia el significado de la frase, perdiendose el sentido imperativo y pasando a ser una frase puramente enunciativa. La preposición "a" (al = a + el) sirve para indicar el objeto indirecto [[DRAE]](https://dle.rae.es/?id=002rZ9U%7C003Ov93), sobre quien debe recaer la muerte ordenada. No se emplea "de" para indicar dicho elemento de una frase.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!